# How can I modify a variable in a list comprehension?

Tags: python

Is there any way to reassign `alt_index` once per loop run in the following code?

```
alt_index = random.randint(0, len(validinfo) - 1)
```

To that list:

```
futures = [
    session.post(f"https://api.mojang.com/user/profile/{validinfo[alt_index].rpartition(':')[-1].rpartition(':')[-1]}/name", headers={'Authorization': "Bearer "+validinfo[alt_index].rpartition(':')[0].rpartition(':')[-1]}, json={"name": TARGET,"password": validinfo[alt_index].rpartition(':')[0].rpartition(':')[0].rpartition(':')[-1]})
    for i in range(TRIES)
]
```

Every request should use a different `alt_index` but in the same expression it must be the same.
I use this to make every request use different data from a txt file.
When I add `alt_index = random.randint(0, len(validinfo) - 1)` to list it throws an error, I don't know how can I fix this.

Comment: I have edited your question to make it more clear based on my understanding of your question. If this is incorrect you can rollback my edit. In the future it would be good to show the error you got when you tried your solution and the corresponding code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a list comprehension, in which you would like to do "additional work". While there are various hacks to pack everything in one line, you can simply fall back to a normal for loop. Any list comprehension `[f(x) for x in y if g(x)]` can be extended to a for loop:

```
return_list = []
for x in y:
    if g(x):
        return_list.append(f(x))
```

You can use then have more complex expressions in there, in your case the corresponding for loop would look the following way:

```
futures = []

for i n range(TRIES):
    futures.append(session.post(f"https://api.mojang.com/user/profile/{validinfo[alt_index].rpartition(':')[-1].rpartition(':')[-1]}/name", headers={'Authorization': "Bearer "+validinfo[alt_index].rpartition(':')[0].rpartition(':')[-1]}, json={"name": TARGET,"password": validinfo[alt_index].rpartition(':')[0].rpartition(':')[0].rpartition(':')[-1]}))
```

You can now reassign `alt_index` in that for loop. It would probably also be a good idea to have some intermedient values, to make that long line easier to read e.g. you often have `validinfo[alt_index].rpartition(':')[0]` in there, which would be a good candidate.

Comment: validated.txt file content is in format "login:password:bearer:id", if I will do it like you said it will randomize everything and credentials will be invalid.